# Why is my program not reading all of characters in the string?

Tags: c++

I need to input a string, if the string is just a whole string and not with spaces, the codes is fine, if the input is a string with spaces, the string only copys the first set of strings and not the whole strings? I'm an noob, please help.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char again = 0;
    do {
        char str[60], s[60];
        int i, j = 0;

        printf("Enter any string->");
        scanf("%s", str);
        printf("The string is->%s", str);

        for (i = 0; i <= strlen(str); i++) {

            if (str[i] == 'a' || str[i] == 'e' || str[i] == 'i' ||
                str[i] == 'o' || str[i] == 'u' || str[i] == 'A' ||
                str[i] == 'E' || str[i] == 'I' || str[i] == 'O' ||
                str[i] == 'U') {

                str[i] = ' ';

            } else {
                s[j++] = str[i];
            }
        }

        s[j] = '\0';
        printf("\nThe string without vowel is->%s", s);
        NSLog(@"Do you want to enter another string to be edit? (y/n) ");
        scanf("%s", &again);
    } while (again != 'n');
}
```

Comment: You have an *objective-c* statement in your code (`NSLog(@"Do you want to enter another string to be edit? (y/n) ");`) and your question is tagged *c++*

Answer (score 1):

Your code stops reading at a space because **that's how `scanf` works** with the `%s` format. It reads a sequence of non-whitespace characters.

If you're really using C++, then you'd be wise to switch to `std::string` and `std::getline`, which will read all input up to the end of the line. Your code doesn't appear to use any C++ features, though, so maybe you're really using C. In that case, consider `fgets` instead. It will read the whole line, too (up to a specified size, which generally corresponds to the size of your buffer).

Answer (score 0):

You are allocating an array of 60 chars long (str). You can't expect to read a lot into it. Here are a few tips:

- Don't use such buffers, they are dangerous. The C++ library provides you [std::string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string).
- Never omit the curly braces `{}`.
- There are an easier way to check for chars than this horribly long if. Hint: [std::string::find_first_of](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find_first_of)

Answer (score 0):

This code is a mess.

- C++ features like `std::string` are not used at all.
- You're mixing `printf/scanf` and `NSLog` for no reason.
- Modifying `str` in the `if` branch makes no sense, as it won't be read later.
- You probably want to use `i < strlen(str)` instead of `<=`, or you'll copy that terminating zero character twice.
- Your `scanf("%s", &again);` specifies to read a string, but you only have memory for a character, thus you probably end up writing into some random memory position.

While some of these points are more severe than others, I suggest fixing those issues and see what happens. If you experience unexpected output, then please do give your example input and output as well.